# Why System.ValueType is not a ValueType?

Tags: c#

Why this expression

```
typeof(System.ValueType).IsValueType
```

return false?

Comment: Returns true if the Type is a value type; otherwise, false.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype(v=vs.110).aspx): "*This property returns false for the ValueType class, because ValueType is not a value type itself. It is the base class for all value types, and therefore any value type can be assigned to it. This would not be possible if ValueType itself was a value type. Value types are boxed when they are assigned to a field of type ValueType.*"

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [Type.IsValueType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This property returns false for the **ValueType class**, because **ValueType**
>   is not a value type itself. It is the base class for all value types,
>   and therefore any value type can be assigned to it. This would not be
>   possible if ValueType itself was a value type. Value types are boxed
>   when they are assigned to a field of type **ValueType**.

From MSDN [ValueType Class (System)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you
>   cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead,
>   individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as
>   struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support
>   the creation of value types.

Therefore as it is a class and not a structure one would expect it to be a reference type as the first link points out.